# lining up function parameter lists with vim

Tags: vim, editor, whitespace

When defining or calling functions with enough arguments to span multiple lines, I want vim to line them up. For example,

```
def myfunction(arg1, arg2, arg, ...
               argsN-1, argN)
```

The idea is for argsN-1 to have its 'a' lined up with args1.

Does anyone have a way to have this happen automatically in vim? I've seen the align plugin for lining equal signs (in assignment statements) and such, but I'm not sure if it can be made to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11):

The previous poster had it, but forgot the `set`

```
:set cino=(0<Enter>
```

From `:help cinoptions-values`

```
The 'cinoptions' option sets how Vim performs indentation.  In the list below,
"N" represents a number of your choice (the number can be negative).  When
there is an 's' after the number, Vim multiplies the number by 'shiftwidth':
"1s" is 'shiftwidth', "2s" is two times 'shiftwidth', etc.  You can use a
decimal point, too: "-0.5s" is minus half a 'shiftwidth'.  The examples below
assume a 'shiftwidth' of 4.

...

    (N    When in unclosed parentheses, indent N characters from the line
          with the unclosed parentheses.  Add a 'shiftwidth' for every
          unclosed parentheses.  When N is 0 or the unclosed parentheses
          is the first non-white character in its line, line up with the
          next non-white character after the unclosed parentheses.
          (default 'shiftwidth' * 2).

            cino=                     cino=(0 >
              if (c1 && (c2 ||          if (c1 && (c2 ||
                          c3))                     c3))
                  foo;                      foo;
              if (c1 &&                 if (c1 &&
                      (c2 || c3))           (c2 || c3))
                 {                         {
```

Comment: Indenting wasn't working at all until I realized that the <Enter> wasn't supposed to be typed out! The value of the variable is simply:
**(0**

Comment: Yeah, this is perhaps more confusing than the other answer

Answer (score 7):

I believe you have to issue the command:

```
:set cino=(0
```

This is when using cindent of course.

edit: I missed "set"

Comment: I think you mean :set cino=(0

Answer (score 2):

Try the Align http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294 and AutoAlign http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=884 scripts.

Answer (score 1):

you might get some good mileage out of using a language-specific external tool as a Vim filter.  for example, if you can write a [Perltidy](http://perltidy.sf.net) config file to generate the formatting you want (it looks like you would want the **-lp -vtc=2** flags), you can then pipe your existing Vim buffer through it with

```
:!/path/to/tidy -config /path/to/configfile
```

if you're going to be running this sort of command frequently, you can define an command by putting something like the following in your .vimrc:

```
command -range=% Tidy <line1>,<line2>!/path/to/tidy -config /path/to/configfile
```