# Vim: Problems with indentation/alignment

Tags: c, vim, coding-style

So I've got a problem (obviously). I read an [interesting article about "Smart Tabs"](http://www.emacswiki.org/SmartTabs), and I've tested this in Emacs and it works perfectly fine.

So currently I'm using Emacs because I've tried this in vim and I can't quite get it to work. Here are the lines of my .vimrc which I think are pertinent to indentation.

```
set autoindent                " auto/smart indentation
set cindent
set preserveindent
set copyindent
set smarttab                  " tab and backspace are smart
set tabstop=4                 " 4 spaces
set softtabstop=4
```

If you think something else could be causing the unexpected behavior as outlined below, [my vimrc is here for you](http://pastebin.com/A0T79Vnb).

## EXPECTED BEHAVIOR

I want a sample program to look like this, with me only typing the code and pressing the enter key every-so-often.
(each "->  " represents a tab, each "." represents a space)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
->  printf ("%s\n",
->  ........teststring);
->  function_with_many_arguments (bacon,
->  ..............................indentation,
->  ..............................problems);
->  return 0;
}
</pre>
```

That is, I want vim to use tabs ONLY for indentation; *NEVER* for alignment.
This is because if someone decreases their tab size, I want the function calls and multi-line argument sets to be aligned properly regardless of how many characters a tab is equal to.

## CURRENT BEHAVIOR

I've looked at all of the resources I could find, and that's how I put together my vimrc.
Right now, instead of doing the expected behavior, this is what code looks like instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
->  printf ("%s\n",
->  ->  ->  teststring);
->  function_with_many_arguments (bacon,
->  ->  ->  indentation,
->  ->  ->  problems);
->  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It looks to me like any and all alignment is just two tab characters, whatever they happen to be, and I want it to indent to the right column with spaces instead.

Comment: `:set cino=(0` taken form [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88931/lining-up-function-parameter-lists-with-vim)

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't answer the (mixed tab / space) indentation part, and unfortunately, that's hard to achieve automatically in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem went away from me when i started using YouCompleteMe plugin with clang completion. Btw it's one of the best plugins if you seriously want to develop C in Vim.